# Syntax Error Updating Records

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a form and subform. Im trying to allow updates in the subform with the use of buttons. However my code is giving me.

KEY_ID is text, the other two are number types.

**"Syntax error in query expression "5", ROOM=5. DRAWER=55 (this is the new value i tried to change it to) WHERE KEY_ID=5'.**

This is an image of my form: http://jumpshare.com/b/17A7Pr

This is what im trying:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
If Me.keyID.Tag & "" = "" Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO KEYS(KEY_ID, ROOM, DRAWER)" & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.keyID & "'," & Me.roomID & "," & Me.drawerID & ")"
          subKey.Form.Requery
Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KEYS " & _
    " SET KEY_ID=" & Chr(39) & keyID & Chr(39) & _
    ", ROOM=" & Me.roomID & _
    ", DRAWER=" & Me.drawerID & _
    " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID.Tag
    Debug.Print KEY_ID
End If
```

Solution:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KEYS " & _
" SET KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID & _
", ROOM=" & Me.roomID & _
", DRAWER=" & Me.drawerID & _
" WHERE KEY_ID=" & Chr(39) & keyID.Tag & Chr(39)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KEYS " & _
" SET KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID & _
", ROOM=" & Me.roomID & _
", DRAWER=" & Me.drawerID & _
" WHERE KEY_ID=" & Chr(39) & keyID.Tag & Chr(39)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code without Chr(39).. This should work.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
If Me.keyID.Tag & "" = "" Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO KEYS(KEY_ID, ROOM, DRAWER)" & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.keyID & "'," & Me.roomID & "," & Me.drawerID & ")"
          subKey.Form.Requery
Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KEYS " & _
    " SET KEY_ID=" &  keyID  & _
    ", ROOM=" & Me.roomID & _
    ", DRAWER=" & Me.drawerID & _
    " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID.Tag
    Debug.Print KEY_ID
End If
```

Comment: I solved this problem. You are partly correct. When setting KEY_ID there is no need for single quotes (chr(39)). However you need it for WHERE stm because KEY_ID is TEXT.